# how to execute method in database field rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord, field

Stop.where("arrival > ?", Time.now.seconds_since_midnight).sort("arrival ASC").first

how can i call seconds_since_midnight in a database field? (arrival is the database field)

Cheers

Comment: It's not being called "in a database field", it's evaluated, and the results used to replace the `?` placeholder before the SQL is generated.

Comment: the problem is that i want to compare how many seconds since midnight of the db entries with Time.now.minutes_since_midnight
  `create_table "stops", force: true do |t|
       t.integer  "route_id"
       t.time     "arrival"
       t.string   "location"
       t.string   "address"
       t.datetime "created_at"
       t.datetime "updated_at"
    end`

Answer (score 0):

This is simple Ruby, do `Stop.where("arrival > ?", Time.now.seconds_since_midnight).sort("arrival ASC").first.arrival.seconds_since_midnight`.

Comment: that didn't work
`SELECT "stops".* FROM "stops"  WHERE (arrival >= 52411.849721)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  operator does not exist: time without time zone >= numeric`

Comment: Oh, I didn't realise that you have :time type column. Try using PostgreSQL [EXTRACT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) function by changing first argument of `where` to `"extract(epoch from arrival) > ?"` or something similar.